# Windows Server hangs after 2-4 weeks of use?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Sorry for the not great title but with the symptoms i'm having its very hard to describe with a short blurb. With a specific server i've been having these wierd symptoms for over a year.

1. Unable to RDP into the box. I recently Sometimes following error from RDP:

   Remote Desktop cannot verify the identity of the remote computer because there is a time or date difference between your computer and the remote computer. Make sure your computer's clock is set to the correct time and then try the connection again.

   Here is the time difference between the client and server:
   Thursday, April 9, 2015 10:51:33 AM
   Thursday, April 9, 2015 10:52:04 AM

   Usually after i enter my password i will get get a black/blank terminal window and it won't go any further .
2. If i try to reboot the computer it will spin forever saying its rebooting but never reboot.
3. If i try to login then it will hang saying its signing into the computer but it will never be successful.

File Sharing still works fine though. So you really don't notice anything until you usually try to login to the server.

The only thing i really have running on the server is Symantec Endpoint Protection (its just primarily used file server). I've even got to the point where i've repaved the machine but the symptoms always return. The hardware is pretty old but up to task for what our needs are (file server). Its a Core 2 Quad system with 8GB Ram.

In the end i always have to do a hard reboot and the machine is fine for 2-4 weeks until the symptoms return. I've tried to slosh through the event viewer but have yet to determine any rhyme or reason why this is occurring.

Short of just trashing the server and getting a new one is there anything at all i can do to determine whats going on?

Comment: Start with figuring out why it's not keeping proper time.

Comment: I appreciate it's not a fix, but if the problem is occurring with a predictable pattern of regularily, then could you create a scheduled task to reboot the server automatically say once a week at 4am? It would also be interesting to see if your problem does in fact disappear having done this.